# Setting pixels at edge of raster to NoData in FME

Tags: fme-form

I am trying to generate GeoTiff rasters using FME Desktop 2015.1.  My input is an 8 bit raster that has areas with pixel values of 0 around its edges.  I want to set these to NoData.

I tried using the RasterBandNodataSetter to set the values to NoData. This was technically successful but pixels with a value of 0 in the middle of my raster were set to NoData as well which is not what I want.

I have also experimented with using the clipper to extract the areas I want hoping that the areas I do not extract would be set to NoData.  However the clipper transformer uses the *rectangular* extent of my clipper feature to clip while I need it to be tapered to the extent of my study area.

I have also tried to write an alpha8 band to the GeoTiff in addition to my main Gray8 band. I was hoping to set the alpha8 to 0 where there is no data so nothing would be displayed. However the GeoTiff writer seems to insist on turning by alpha8 band into a UINT8.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution lies in using the RasterCellColorReplacer tool only after you apply a Perimeter polygon.  Specifically, you apply a perimeter by thresholding the 0-value pixels on the exterior only. The perimeter polygon should be "inside" this exclusion area (so that the 0-value pixels are "outside" the perimeter.)  Next, apply the RCCR tool to only the ClippedOutside result set from the perimeter clipper...use the RCCR to change the 0-pixels to NoData values only outside.  This should give you a full-sized image with NoData mask pixels on the outside and 0-valued pixels un-effected within.

For more details, check out [this FME blog post](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/936/advanced-cell-color-manipulation-with-rastercellva.html) which uses a similar (but not exactly the same approach.)